# how to go through all element in KeyValueStore

Tags: java, apache-samza

I have a KeyValueStore of type KeyValueStore>. I don't know the range of the keys. Is there any way I can iterate through the whole keyvaluestore in samza? Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Sure. Use the all() method on the KeyValueStore instance. That will return an iterator which you can use to scan the whole store.

http://samza.apache.org/learn/documentation/0.12/api/javadocs/org/apache/samza/storage/kv/KeyValueStore.html#all--